# DataTable - Ajax sourced data

Tags: ajax, forms, datatable, submit

I have a table and filled it with ajax 
**TABLE**

```
<table id="tabla_productos"> </table>
```

**Ajax sourced data**

```
var tabla_productos = $('#tabla_productos').DataTable( {
"responsive" : "true",
"ajax": {
    "url": "/funciones/getProductos.php",
    "dataSrc": ""
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "id" },
    { "data": "add_cart" }
]
}});
```

**AJAX DATA**

```
{"id":"2",
 "add_cart":"<form class=\"form-item\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" name=\"product_qty\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"S10881\" name=\"product_code\"><button class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\">Add to Cart<\/button><\/form>" }
```

**jQuery Form submit:**

```
$(".form-item").submit(function(e){
    alert('ok');        
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML OUTPUT: form created from ajax

```
<form class="form-item"><input type="hidden" name="product_qty" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="S10881"><button type="submit" class="btn">Add to Cart</button></form>
```

SAME FORM CREATED FROM HTML:

```
<form class="form-item"><input type="hidden" name="product_qty" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="S10881"><button type="submit" class="btn">Add to Cart</button></form>
```

- When i submit the form created from html it works ok.
- If i submit the form created from ajax it doesn't works.
- If i wait that table fill up with data, it works:

  setTimeout(function(){
   $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
          alert('ok');
          e.preventDefault();
   });
   }, 10000);

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why it doesn't submit the form when i click on submit button? i want to submit the form by clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

i added "initComplete" with form submit function to data table

```
    var tabla_productos = $('#tabla_productos').DataTable( {
"responsive" : "true",
"ajax": {
    "url": "/funciones/getProductos.php",
    "dataSrc": ""
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "id" },
    { "data": "add_cart" }
],
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
  $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
   alert('ok');        
   e.preventDefault();
  });
}
        }});
```